# python - random number and calculations dont work together

Tags: python

I try to generate a random number, then substract this number as percentage from my original price with following code:

```
rndnm = random.sample(range(10, 40), 1)
priceraw = int(price) - (int(price)/100*int(rndnm))
saleprice = str(priceraw)
print(saleprice)
```

nothing gets printed with this. how should i write it that it works?

Comment: How do you run it? From the terminal or..?

Comment: Not true. An error message gets printed.

Comment: yes i imported random in the og code, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
import random

price = 5000

rndnm = random.randint(10, 40)
print(rndnm)

priceraw = int(price) - (int(price)/100*int(rndnm))
saleprice = str(priceraw)
print(saleprice)

#Output
28
3600.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: already worked thx

Answer (score 5):

You generate a list of random numbers. You need to get the first one:

```
rndnm = random.sample(range(10, 40), 1)[0]
```

Comment: Seems like a rather clumsy way to write `random.randrange(10, 40)`, though.

Comment: Another approach would be using `random.randint(10, 39)`. Note that both sides are included, unlike as in `randrange`